# how to remove specific str from dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe which contains "_" on each row, eg:

```
    numbers
0   123
1   321_2
2   2222_2
3   41232_1
4   23123_5
5   45455
6   231231
7   3479_23_23
8   82837_212_fd
```

My purpose is to remove all the string after first '_' for each row, eg:

```
    numbers
0   123
1   321
2   2222
3   41232
4   23123
5   45455
6   231231
7   3479
8   82837
```

then I got an idea using 'split' function:

```
result = s.split("_")[0]
```

However, it cannot apply to the dataframe since I got an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'

My first question is that:
How can I remove str after first '_'?

Moreover, is it possible to just remove '_'  but keep the leading number part?

Comment: try `s.str.split('_')[0]` or `s.numbers.str.split('_')[0]`. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html) for the string methods

Comment: @Haleemur Ali thx for your help, it only works for singe rwos, but I got dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].astype(str).str.split('_').str[0]
df
  numbers
0     123
1     321
2    2222
3   41232
4   23123
5   45455
6  231231
7    3479
8   82837
```

Comment: this is exactly what I have done previously, the only problem of this code is that it removes all rows if does not contains '_' , for exampel: the first row '123' will turn out to be 'nan' insead, as well as for other rows without '_'

Comment: @史超南 adding astype str

Comment: @史超南 do you have dataframe or series ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [BEN_YO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/ben-yo)'s answer.

If it is a series, you can use split function on it.

```py
lst = ['123','321_2','2222_2','41232_1','23123_5','45455','231231','3479_23_23','82837_212_fd']

s = pd.Series(lst)

s
```

```
0             123
1           321_2
2          2222_2
3         41232_1
4         23123_5
5           45455
6          231231
7      3479_23_23
8    82837_212_fd
dtype: object
```

```py
s.str.split('_').str[0]
```

```
0       123
1       321
2      2222
3     41232
4     23123
5     45455
6    231231
7      3479
8     82837
dtype: object
```

However, if it is a dataframe, then replace the **column** value by using the same method.

> df['numbers'] # returns a **Series** and we are applying **split** function on that series.

```py
df = pd.Series(lst).to_frame('numbers')
type(df['numbers'])
```

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

```py
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].str.split('_').str[0]
print(df)
```

```
  numbers
0     123
1     321
2    2222
3   41232
4   23123
5   45455
6  231231
7    3479
8   82837
```